# Laravel Socialite: Invalid request. Missing OAuth verifier. (Twitter)

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, oauth, laravel-socialite

This is my first time working with Socialite and I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Essentially, all I want is to return some account details of the currently authenticated account. I have it working when it comes to logging in and creating an account but when I try to return details using that account I'm greeted with the missing OAuth verifier error.

Here is a short video clip of my authorizing the app as expected and then clicking a link that should return JSON data about the account: https://youtu.be/LE8x9P8N_dU

Inside the controller for returning the account details I have:

```
public function getAccountInfo(){

    $socialAccount = Socialite::with('twitter')->user();
    return $socialAccount;    
}
```

I was under the impression this would let me do things such as

```
$socialAccount->getAvatar();
```

ect however it doesn't appear to work.

I was following this tutorial for setting up Socialite: https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-twitter-login.html so my set up is almost exactly the same as this.

```
"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
"laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I can provide any additional information you need please don't hesitate to ask for it.

Comment: Good question. Keen to see the answer myself

Answer (score 1):

Check this syntax

```
$socialAccount = Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();
```

If you want the account details of the currently authenticated user, use the same old

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Comment: The results between with and driver are the same. I seen some documentation using with and gave it a try. Wouldn't Auth::User only give me access to whatever I saved upon initial account creation? The details such as avatar would go out of date if they were saved.  Do you recommend updating these details every time a user logs in if they have changed?

Comment: Whatever details you intend to use later in the app, you should either save it in the database, or save it in the session. Because when you get the logged-in user via Auth::user(), it takes the user from the database and not from socialite.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was under the impression that once you hit log in you create a 'user' instance (referencing the docs) and that you'd be able to access it using the socialite->user() method. Is this not how it works?https://github.com/laravel/socialite#retrieving-user-details

Comment: @EddyTheDove Could you answer this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961377/cant-detect-callback-is-real-in-laravel-socialite

Answer (score 0):

You can check...
`$request->exists('denied')` for Twitter and `$request->exists('error')` for Linkedin. It working on my application in Laravel 6.0* with Socialite 4.0*.

```
if ($request->exists('denied') || $request->exists('error')) 
{   
    // do something

}else{
    $socialAccount = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
}
```